# to_char function in SQLPLUS

Tags: sql, linux, sqlplus, to-char

When I run `select to_char(SYSDATE-3) from dual`  from SQL DEVELOPER it gives `26-06-15`.
But when I run the same query from SQLPLUS session from Linux its giving -

```
SQL> select TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-3) from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-3)
------------------
26-JUN-15
```

How to correct this in SQLPLUS?

Answer (score 0):

This is the same value in different format.

You can set the session level date format using

```
alter session set nls_date_format='dd-mm-yy';
```

Or you can pass this format in the to_char function

```
select TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-3, 'dd-mm-yy') from dual;
```